# software to recode mp3 files

Tags: software-rec, mp3, encoding

I have a mp3 file which in some players I can't seek properly (for example in Foobar). I think the timing information is messed up. I'm thinking of recoding it, maybe it will fix the problem.

Can you recommend a quick solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/download.htm) for all media recoding. It has a bit of a learning curve (there are plenty of tutorials), but it'll convert a huge number of formats and quite efficiently.